# Есть ли модуль на python который проверяет количество заряда ноута? Как сделать что бы .py файл работал в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сделать утилиту которая будет проверять зарядку ноута и если там <20, то будет сигнал. Но какой нужен модуль? И я хочу что бы эта утилита работала в фоновом режиме, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения информации о батарее можно использовать модуль *psutil*
**Документалка** - https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
**Код** :

```
import psutil
print(psutil.sensors_battery())
```

Если под фоновым режимом подразумевается без консоли тогда можно просто переименовать скрипт из .py в .pyw
Ну а если по фоном подразумевается работа в виде службы можно использовать модуль
**python-daemon**
**Ссылка** - https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/